# Invalid parameter number error on sql case query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, search, pdo

I am trying to create a search query with case and i am stuck on the error 'Invalid parameter number'. Could someone help me with what the issue could be and how i can fix it?

```
$query = 'SELECT *,
  CASE WHEN o.title LIKE :keyword THEN 1
       WHEN c.body LIKE :keyword THEN 2
  ELSE 99 END AS priority
  FROM orders AS o INNER JOIN
    comment_relations AS cr ON o.id = cr.target_id INNER JOIN
    comments AS c ON cr.comment_id = c.id
  WHERE cr.type = 2
  ORDER BY priority';

  $stmt = $db->prepare($query);

  $stmt->bindValue(':keyword', '%' . $search_keyword . '%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

The tables looks like this

```
ORDER:

ID = 95
title = first order


COMMENT RELATIONS:
id = 1241
comment_id = 500
target_id = 95
type = 2

COMMENT: 
id = 500
body = this is the first comment
```

Comment: Is there an error, if you try the query with "hardcoded keywords"? Just for testing the query.

Comment: just a thought, perhaps quoting around the variable like this? `$stmt->bindValue(':keyword', '"%' . $search_keyword . '%"', PDO::PARAM_STR);` ~ note the `"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the problem is related to the usage of a same parameter twice. If you have 2 parameters, you have to specify 2 parameters.

You should try to write 2 different parameters even if they have the same value and see what happens.

Same problem has been reported [here](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=33886)